# bq load fails for GS locations with sub-directories

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

bq load --allow_jagged_rows -F tab --quote="" project-name:dataset-name.table-name  gs://bucket-name/* schema
Waiting on bqjob_r51ee37f56558cb4_0000015331e95c36_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'project-name:bqjob_r51ee37f56558cb4_0000015331e95c36_1': Not found: Uri
gs://bucket-name/mon=2015-02

but the folder + data presence and The command works fine if bucket doesn't have sub folders , anyone can help on this ? is this permission issue ,coz recently changed the authentication

Comment: Could you provide the full command you tried (anonymising anything you don't want to share)? In particular, those three /// don't look right.

Comment: Can you try this again to confirm that it still fails? If so: please provide an approximate timestamp and updated job_id of the load job that failed. This will help us narrow down the logs to investigate. (I'm having trouble finding anything for the job that failed in the original post.) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is an internal error that has been addressed for this project (see the end of [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=190)).

If other customers hit the same issue, please file a new bug at our [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues). In the meantime, we'll attempt to proactively identify affected projects and address the underlying issue.